# Insulating over IC recessed lights

Tags: insulation, attic, recessed-lighting

I am losing a good amount of heat through my recessed lights.  I went up in the attic above and found there is insulation around them, but not on top.  They are IC (insulation contact) rated.  Is it okay to just put more batt insulation on top of them, or is there a better way?  I'm hesitant to cover them because of the wiring.

[image]

Comment: imgur will give a much more reasonable link to the picture (it's also where they end up once we add them, so...might as well put them there to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IC rating means that the entire can can come into contact with insulation.

For more information see http://www.superiorwirework.com/ic-rated-recessed-lighting.asp

Comment: Plus, run lower wattage bulbs in them like CFLs or LEDs, and they won't get that warm in the first place.